# Deploy additional files with Node Lambda Function AWS CDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm trying to deploy my AWS lambda function using the CDK, but I want to bundle other files in the lambda as well (JSON files). How do I go about this other than using CommandHooks and copying the files myself? For reference, I'm not importing the file. A library I'm using is importing it and requires the path to the file as a string. I've tried using the loader option, but that changes the name of the file and breaks the path that the library was given.

For reference, this works: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/11468

but I'd prefer not to have to do that for every lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the functions all share the same files, then you might prefer to create a [Lambda layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) to copy the files over.

If each function requires different files however, then the bundling option is just as easy. It's IAC after all, so you can just create a helper function to make it a bit less repetitive.